# struts2 spring jpa layers best practice

Tags: spring, struts2

I have an app written with Struts2 Spring3 JPA2 and hibernate. In this app i have the following levels :
- struts2 actions
- spring services
- spring DAO

So, one struts action call for a service which can contain calls to one or many dao objects.
In order to display the info on the screen i have created some "mirror" objects for entities; ie: EmailMessage entity has a EmailMessageForm bean that is used to display/gather data from webforms (i don`t know if this is the best practice), and hence my problem.
In EmailMessageServiceImpl i have a method called:

```
 public List < EmailMessage > getEmailMessages(){ 
     //code here   
 }
```

and, if i call this from struts action i cannot get dependencies because session has expired (i have TRANSACTION entity manager). So, one solution would be to create another method

```
List<EmailMessageForm> getEmailMessagesForDisplay()
{
//....
}
```

and here to call for getEmailMessages() and convert this to form objects.
What do you recommend me ?
What is the best practice for this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "dependencies" you mean "lazy-loaded objects", IMO it's best to get all the required data before hitting the view layer. In your current architecture it looks like that would mean a service method that retrieves the DTOs ("form beans"; I hesitate to use the term since it's easy to confuse with Struts 1).

Some say using an Open Session in View filter/interceptor is better. It's easier, but can lead to unintended consequences if the view developer isn't paying attention, including multiple N+1 queries etc.

Comment: well, yes the dependencies are some lazy loaded objects. That`s what i`m trying to accomplish (get all necessary data before hitting the view layer). So the approach with a method in service layer that fetch the data (using a dao object) and then creates and returns dto for the struts action is ok, right ?